# Hibernate Detached entity error - different result per environment

Tags: hibernate, java-8, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1

we have a Java back end application (created using Java 9) and we are currently encountering this issue upon table record insert via Hibernate.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
```

The thing is, this only happens when inserting into our table in UAT environment. When doing the same insert in the SIT and DEV database, this does not happen. We already verified that the codes in UAT and SIT/DEV are the same and also verified the tables structures are the same. What else could possible cause this exception?

Below is the snippet of the entity class we used:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_TABLE")
public class SomeTable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "SOME_TABLE_ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "someTableSeq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "someTableSeq", sequenceName = "SOME_TABLE_SEQ",
      allocationSize = 1)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "FIELD_ONE")
  private String fieldOne;

  @Column(name = "FIELD_TWO")
  private String fieldTwo;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "CREATED_DT")
  private Date createdDt;




Settings:
hibernate-core version: 5.2.10
hibernate-jpa version:  2.1
spring: 4.3.0-RELEASE
Database: Oracle 12c
```

Comment: The issue will be somewhere in your transaction demarcation, a missing cascade or trying to update a record when the corresponding instance is not managed by Hibernate (and probably there are a few more scenarios)... which means somewhere in the code. About why it works in one environment and not in others, there are probably thousands of reasons why this might be the case. One suggestion would be to compare stack traces at the point of saving the record, and/or also check if the instances are managed before an (explicit or implicit) call to `em.persist()`.

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace and some code how you persist the entity?